# Start local meteor app after windows boot

Tags: windows, meteor

A local meteor (1.2) application should get started in the background right after windows has been booted. What are my options to get the job done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following steps, if you want to start Meteor automatically when a user logs in:

1. Create a batch file.
2. Open the newly created batch file and place the following lines into it:

---

```
@echo off
cd "<the path to your Meteor project>"
meteor
timeout /t 10
start "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe" http://localhost:3000
```

3. Create a shortcut:

[image: Batch-Shortcut]

4. Open the Run window (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).
5. Open `shell:startup` (or go to: `C:\Users\John Doe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`).
6. Copy the shortcut into the folder.

Now, when a user logs in, Meteor should start your project and Microsoft Edge should open `http://localhost:3000` after 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Applications cannot run without a user being logged in. So "started in the background right after windows has been booted" is not something that is going to happen. You would need a service for that, and services are not interactive. Assuming that you're talking about the Meteor JS framework, you can't build a service out of that.

If you're talking about starting an application when a user logs in, then you can do that easily by adding a shortcut to the executable to the user's "Startup" folder. On modern versions of Windows, the path would be something like:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the Meteor JS framework and an application which was created using this framework. Right now I open cmd.exe, browse to the path where my meteor application exists and start it by entering the command 'meteor'. Afterwards I can access the application by calling http://localhost:3000. However I want to achieve the following workflow: 1. System boots. 2. User logs in  3. System calls the meteor command in the background without user interaction 4. User calls the local URL. I don't know how tho use just a shortcut for this steps. Can you help me to figure it out?